# conditional css not working correctly?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

i have used condition css for internet explorer to show the auto cursor in internet explore but it is not working correctly
i have used following code to link the

```
<!--[if IE]><link rel="stylesheet" href="newstyle_ie.css" media="screen" type="text/css" /><![endif]-->
```

i have to show the default cursor in internet explore for that i uses

> body{ cursor:auto !important;}

and for other browsers i have used

> body{ cursor:url("some url");}

any hint ???

Comment: can you provide any link?

Comment: What does “not working correctly” mean? What happens in IE? Is `newstyle_ie.css` the right location?

Comment: it is still showing the image cursor in internet explorer but i am wanted to show the default cursor in internet explorer

Comment: Which version of IE are you testing in? IE 10+ doesn’t support conditional comments.

Comment: i am testing it on IE10

Answer (score 0):

Your conditional comment is ok, you should check the cursor url, and set a fallback value(i.e. pointer, separated with a comma), just in case the first cursor isn't found. Also check the path to css file

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
body {
    cursor:  auto;
    cursor:  url(url path), auto;
}
```

**or**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").css('cursor','url(your url),auto');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try to use hack css for browser to fix your issue .
Please refer this link http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/ how to call hack css.

Thanks.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to provide the actual information here and not just a link. [Link-only answers are not considered good answers and will probably be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).